# Logging separately from Spring app into Elastic stack

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot app, and an Elastic stack (Elasticsearch + Kibana + Filebeat, no Logstash). I want to log some information whenever a request comes to my Spring app (say, the request url and request user id).

A first naive way is to simply log that (`log.info("request comes url={} user={}", url, user);`).  Then filebeat will happily collect that into my elasticsearch and I can visualize it using Kibana.

However, I do not want these data to be mixed with *all* the other logs in the `filebeat-*` index pattern. I want them to be, say, `request-info` (or `request-info-*`) while the other normal log data in `filebeat-*` index pattern. Is there any way to do so? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional output in your `filebeat.yml` based on a string present in your message.

Something like:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
  indices:
    - index: "request-info-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        message: "request comes"
```

If your message contains the string `request comes` it will be sent to the index `request-info-2020.11.28` for example, if it does not contains, it will be sent to the default index.

You can read more about the options to the `elasticsearch output` in this [documentation link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#indices-option-es)

Comment: Oh great, thank you! I knew `index` and `when`, but did not think that it can be *conditionally* set like this :)